# Capistrano, Could not find turbolinks-source-5.0.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I have updated all my gems in my local computer then I have changed `lock` version in my `deploy.rb` file.

Then I try to run `cap production deploy`

When it gets to `bundle:install` section, it throws to me this error:

```
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as  user@user.kz: bundle exit status: 7
bundle stdout: Could not find turbolinks-source-5.0.0 in any of the sources
bundle stderr: Nothing written

 DEBUG [f860873c] Command: cd /var/www/techgarden-server-app/releases/20161017101600 && /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --path /var/www/techgarden-server-app/shared/
 bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet

 DEBUG [f860873c]       Could not find turbolinks-source-5.0.0 in any of the sources
```

Why this error happening now?

My `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'capistrano-sidekiq', github: 'seuros/capistrano-sidekiq'

gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

gem 'whenever', :require => false

gem 'ckeditor'

gem 'file_validators'

gem 'sucker_punch', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'rest-client'

gem 'koala'

gem 'faker'
gem 'kaminari'

gem 'puma'

gem 'enumerize'
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'mongoid-grid_fs', github: 'ahoward/mongoid-grid_fs'
gem 'carrierwave-mongoid', :require => 'carrierwave/mongoid'
gem 'mini_magick'

gem 'rails_admin', github: 'sferik/rails_admin'

gem 'devise'

gem 'grape'
gem 'grape-swagger', github: 'ruby-grape/grape-swagger'
gem 'grape-swagger-rails'

gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0' 
gem 'therubyrhino'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano',         require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm',     require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails',   require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano3-puma',   require: false
end
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'nokogiri', '>=1.6.8.rc3'
```

My `Gemfile.lock`:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/ahoward/mongoid-grid_fs.git
  revision: 047ddda03b1865ab7feaa8be6bc8d8e1cefa7d7a
  specs:
    mongoid-grid_fs (2.2.2)
      mime-types (>= 1.0, < 4.0)
      mongoid (>= 3.0, < 7.0)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-swagger.git
  revision: 7061fd1b7537277d24678a5e249afcd8b965a503
  specs:
    grape-swagger (0.24.0)
      grape (>= 0.12.0)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq.git
  revision: 951995f08e1aa790fff3a2cf18b0c3a3c8bf918d
  specs:
    capistrano-sidekiq (0.5.4)
      capistrano
      sidekiq (>= 3.4)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git
  revision: b92a4d1a30b706d08df2aee4d0a59dad698a0552
  specs:
    rails_admin (1.0.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      coffee-rails (~> 4.0)
      font-awesome-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      haml (~> 4.0)
      jquery-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 5.0)
      kaminari (~> 0.14)
      nested_form (~> 0.3)
      rack-pjax (>= 0.7)
      rails (>= 4.0, < 6)
      remotipart (~> 1.3)
      sass-rails (>= 4.0, < 6)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.6)
      actionpack (= 4.2.6)
      actionview (= 4.2.6)
      activejob (= 4.2.6)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.6)
      actionview (= 4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.6)
      activemodel (= 4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.6)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.4.0)
    airbrussh (1.1.1)
      sshkit (>= 1.6.1, != 1.7.0)
    arel (6.0.3)
    axiom-types (0.1.1)
      descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.4)
      ice_nine (~> 0.11.0)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.1)
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    bson (4.1.1)
    builder (3.2.2)
    capistrano (3.6.1)
      airbrussh (>= 1.0.0)
      capistrano-harrow
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.9.0)
    capistrano-bundler (1.2.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-harrow (0.5.3)
    capistrano-rails (1.1.8)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano3-puma (1.2.1)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      puma (>= 2.6)
    carrierwave (0.11.2)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      json (>= 1.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      mimemagic (>= 0.3.0)
    carrierwave-mongoid (0.10.0)
      carrierwave (>= 0.8.0, < 0.12.0)
      mongoid (>= 3.0, < 7.0)
      mongoid-grid_fs (>= 1.3, < 3.0)
    chronic (0.10.2)
    ckeditor (4.2.0)
      cocaine
      orm_adapter (~> 0.5.0)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.8)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coercible (1.0.0)
      descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.1)
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    commonjs (0.2.7)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
    connection_pool (2.2.0)
    descendants_tracker (0.0.4)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.1)
    devise (4.2.0)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 5.1)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    domain_name (0.5.20160826)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    enumerize (2.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2)
    equalizer (0.0.11)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    faker (1.6.6)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    faraday (0.9.2)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    ffi (1.9.14)
    file_validators (2.1.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.0)
    font-awesome-rails (4.6.3.1)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.1)
    globalid (0.3.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    grape (0.18.0)
      activesupport
      builder
      hashie (>= 2.1.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.3.2)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
      mustermann-grape (~> 0.4.0)
      rack (>= 1.3.0)
      rack-accept
      virtus (>= 1.0.0)
    grape-swagger-rails (0.3.0)
      railties (>= 3.2.12)
    haml (4.0.7)
      tilt
    hashie (3.4.6)
    http-cookie (1.0.3)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    ice_nine (0.11.2)
    jbuilder (2.6.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.2.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.3)
    kaminari (0.17.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    koala (2.4.0)
      addressable
      faraday
      multi_json (>= 1.3.0)
    less (2.6.0)
      commonjs (~> 0.2.7)
    less-rails (2.8.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      less (~> 2.6.0)
      sprockets (> 2, < 4)
      tilt
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mimemagic (0.3.2)
    mini_magick (4.5.1)
    mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
    minitest (5.9.1)
    mongo (2.3.0)
      bson (~> 4.1)
    mongoid (5.1.4)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
      mongo (~> 2.1)
      origin (~> 2.2)
      tzinfo (>= 0.3.37)
    multi_json (1.12.1)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    mustermann (0.4.0)
      tool (~> 0.2)
    mustermann-grape (0.4.0)
      mustermann (= 0.4.0)
    nested_form (0.3.2)
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (3.2.0)
    netrc (0.11.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.8.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
    origin (2.2.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    puma (3.6.0)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-accept (0.4.5)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-pjax (1.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      rack (>= 1.1)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.6)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.6)
      actionpack (= 4.2.6)
      actionview (= 4.2.6)
      activejob (= 4.2.6)
      activemodel (= 4.2.6)
      activerecord (= 4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.6)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.2.6)
      actionpack (= 4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (11.3.0)
    rdoc (4.2.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redis (3.3.1)
    remotipart (1.3.1)
    responders (2.3.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.1)
    rest-client (2.0.0)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4.0)
      netrc (~> 0.8)
    sass (3.4.22)
    sass-rails (5.0.6)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (0.4.2)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    sidekiq (4.2.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      connection_pool (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.0)
      rack-protection (~> 1.5)
      redis (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.1)
    sprockets (3.7.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sshkit (1.11.3)
      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)
    sucker_punch (2.0.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0.0)
    therubyrhino (2.0.4)
      therubyrhino_jar (>= 1.7.3)
    therubyrhino_jar (1.7.6)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.5)
    tool (0.2.3)
    turbolinks (5.0.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5)
    turbolinks-source (5.0.0)
    twitter-bootstrap-rails (3.2.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      execjs (>= 2.2.2, >= 2.2)
      less-rails (>= 2.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2016.7)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    uglifier (3.0.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.2)
    virtus (1.0.5)
      axiom-types (~> 0.1)
      coercible (~> 1.0)
      descendants_tracker (~> 0.0, >= 0.0.3)
      equalizer (~> 0.0, >= 0.0.9)
    warden (1.2.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    whenever (0.9.7)
      chronic (>= 0.6.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby
DEPENDENCIES
  capistrano
  capistrano-bundler
  capistrano-rails
  capistrano-rvm
  capistrano-sidekiq!
  capistrano3-puma
  carrierwave-mongoid
  ckeditor
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  devise
  enumerize
  faker
  file_validators
  grape
  grape-swagger!
  grape-swagger-rails
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  kaminari
  koala
  mini_magick
  mongoid
  mongoid-grid_fs!
  nokogiri (>= 1.6.8.rc3)
  puma
  rails (= 4.2.6)
  rails_admin!
  rest-client
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  sidekiq
  sucker_punch (~> 2.0)
  therubyrhino
  turbolinks
  twitter-bootstrap-rails
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  whenever

BUNDLED WITH
   1.12.5
```

Comment: Can you show your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock?

Comment: @rootatdarkstar I have added gemfile and lockfile

Comment: @Mr.D is your local and server ruby version same?

Comment: @SachinSingh Yes they are both 2.3. However, I think it does not important, because I was able to use 2.1 in my local and 2.3 in my prodution server.

Comment: Make sure you are using bundler 1.12.5 on the server (since that is what was used to generate the lock file).

Comment: I was able to deploy my project when I downgraded my Capistrano

Answer (score 4):

Use bundle install --full-index.  It uses the rubygems modern index instead of the API endpoint. Solved my problem.